# How do I properly handle Python 3's Popen.communicate() timeout?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I find the documentation on [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) somewhat incomplete. Take the example from the documentation, with a slight modification:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
try :                                                                       
    outs, errs = p.communicate(ins, timeout=5)                             
except TimeoutExpired:                                                      
    p.kill()                                                
    outs, errs = p.communicate(ins) # What's with the input data?                                         
# What value does p.returncode have at this point?
```

Then I have two questions:

1. If I send input `ins` to the child process, do I resend the input after catching the timeout exception? Does this handle already read input correctly?
2. What will be the value (if any) of [`p.returncode`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError.returncode) after calling [`p.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill), i.e. after sending a `SIGKILL` to the process?

Answer (score 0):

1. After killing the process, it makes no sense to send it input. The final `p.communicate` reads data in the pipes.
2. Indeterminate. The process might exit on its own between the timeout and `p.kill` in the exception handler, with whatever exit code. Otherwise, the [`p.returncode`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) doc says

   > "A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (POSIX only)."

   So `-SIGKILL` on POSIX. On Windows? If that matters to you, try it and see.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm actually tempted to skip `communicate` after the `kill` altogether because the data is quite likely incomplete anyway—at least in my case. (Although on POSIX it seems I ought to be able to check the `returncode` and see if maybe the process finished before the `kill`.) I just added a link to the *other* `Popen.returncode` doc with your citation; I didn't see that first time 'round.

Comment: @Jens: `.returncode` is None until you've called `.wait()` or `.communicate()` and they returned successfully (or `.poll()` returned a non-None value). The second `.communicate()` call should drop `ins` parameter i.e., use `p.communicate()`,  not `p.communicate(ins)`. Use `p.communicate()` even if you don't need the buffered output, to close the pipes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I could have saved me from posting this question by reading the [`subprocess` code](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.4/file/tip/Lib/subprocess.py) :) Note that the module implements some internals differently for [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) and Windows, and at this point I care only for the POSIX implementation.

So here is my take on all this which largely verifies what has been answered already.

1. Passing `ins` a second time to `communicate()` after killing the child process upon timeout will raise a `ValueError` exception stating that `Cannot send input after starting communication` (see [here](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.4/file/tip/Lib/subprocess.py#l930)).
2. Note that [Terry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489341/how-do-i-properly-handle-python-3s-popen-communicate-time-out/34501037#34501037) covers this. The `returncode` is initially set to `None`.

   - If the child process terminated between raising the timeout exception and sending the kill signal, then `kill()` won't send a signal (see [here](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.4/file/tip/Lib/subprocess.py#l1684)) and the second call to `communicate()` will simply gather the output data and `returncode` contains a proper value.
   - Otherwise the second call to `communicate()` [will `wait()`](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.4/file/tip/Lib/subprocess.py#l1652) until the child process is dead, set the return code value to `-SIGKILL` (see [here](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.4/file/tip/Lib/subprocess.py#l1467)) as part of the wait, and then gather the output data.

   Which means that I can use `p.returncode` after the try-except block in the question, and it will tell me if the child process terminated correctly or not.

Comment: [I have to repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489341/how-do-i-properly-handle-python-3s-popen-communicate-timeout#comment56747915_34501037): `.returncode` does NOT update itself magically. You have to call `.wait()`, `.communicate()` or `.poll()`, to update it. Therefore if `.communicate()` raises `TimeoutError` then `.returncode` is `None`  **always** -- no race condition. You should call `.wait()` to set `.returncode` after the `.kill()` call if you haven't redirected stdin/stdout/stderr, otherwise call `.communicate()` to close the pipes and set `.returncode`.

Comment: Actually, `.communicate()` locks up reproducibly after a `kill()` in my scenario, and I could trace it down to the `select(timeout=None)` call [here](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.4/file/tip/Lib/selectors.py#l314). Only the output was piped and registered for that SelectSelector. Not quite sure what's going on exactly here... yet.

Comment: it means that the subprocess spawn its own child processes that inherit the pipes and survive `.kill()` (their parent is killed by they go on). How to kill an arbitrary family of processes is application dependent. If children do not change their process group then use: `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` and `os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)` to kill the whole process group. If you don't care about the surviving descendants then close pipes manually (`pipe.close()`) and call `p.wait()` after `p.kill()`.

Comment: You refer to [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true/4791612#4791612), correct?

Comment: yes, it is similar. Though notice that the details differ.